# Iterate through the rows of a dataframe and reassign minimum values by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataframe that looks like this.

```
  id time diff
0 0   34   nan
1 0   36   2
2 1   43   7
3 1   55   12
4 1   59   4
5 2   2    -57
6 2   10   8
```

What is an efficient way find the minimum values for 'time' by id, then set 'diff' to nan at those minimum values. I am looking for a solution that results in:

```
   id time diff
0 0   34   nan
1 0   36   2
2 1   43   nan
3 1   55   12
4 1   59   4
5 2   2    nan
6 2   10   8
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an example, but I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Find the minimum values by id and set them to nans? Why then is the 7 set to nan for id=1 and not the 4?

Comment: I am trying to set the item with the least time per group of id's to nan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`groupby('id')` and use `idxmin` to find the location of minimum values of `'time'`.  Finally, use `loc` to assign `np.nan`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id').time.idxmin(), 'diff'] = np.nan
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can group the time by id and calculate a logical vector where if the time is minimum within the group, the value is True, else False, and use the logical vector to assign `NaN` to the corresponding rows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['time'].apply(lambda g: g == min(g)), "diff"] = np.nan

df
#  id   time    diff
#0  0     34    NaN
#1  0     36    2.0
#2  1     43    NaN
#3  1     55    12.0
#4  1     59    4.0
#5  2      2    NaN
#6  2     10    8.0
```